# View app crash reports

Tags: lumia, windows-10-mobile

Is there any way to see some kind of crash report for apps?

I don't mean online for my apps as a developer. I mean something like Windows' **Event Viewer**.

Answer (score 0):

It was a way using the app "Field Medic" from Microsoft.  But apparently after anniversary update the field medic does not "see" the reports that are being generated by the system or apps.